# ¿Cómo redireccionar a una página y que se cargue el valor de un select?

Tags: html, html-select, href

Estoy redireccionando a una página que contiene un formulario. Esta página contiene el formulario en una sección específica de ella. Para que se redireccione a la página y a la sección especifica le coloqué el elemento en su *url* de la siguiente manera:

```html
<a id="eres_contacto" href="https://localhost:44329/contacto/#contacto">¿Eres contacto?</a><br />
```

Una vez redireccione a este formulario tengo un `select` con algunos valores. Pero allí deseo que al momento de redireccionar a la página se me cargue en el `select` un valor en específico.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código tengo los siguientes valores:

```html
<select id="SelectFiltro" name="SelectFiltro" class="form-control form-control-lg select " data-native-menu="false" >
  <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">Ejemplo 1</option>
  <option value="2">Ejemplo 2</option>
  <option value="3">Ejemplo 3</option>
  <option value="4">Ejemplo 4</option>
  <option value="5">Ejemplo 5</option>
  <option value="6">Ejemplo 6</option>
</select>
```

El valor en específico que quiero que cargue al momento de redireccionar es el **6 - Ejemplo 6.**

No sé si tenga que añadir algo más a mi *url* en `href` para que se cargue cierto valor en el `select` tras haber redireccionado a este formulario.

Comment: Hola... el <a> y el <select> se encuentran en la misma pagina: en dos lugares de la misma, o son dos paginas diferentes?
Y además me puedes indicar si la opción 6 que mencionas es la que siempre debe elegirse por default?

Comment: @Claudio El `<a>` y el `<select>` se encuentran en diferentes paginas, la opción 6 es la que debe mostrarse en mi formulario después de redireccionar, solo en este caso cuando redirecciono desde la otra pagina.

Answer (score 0):

Para poner como default una de las opciones, debes agregar selected="selected" a la deseada. Tu código en el formulario quedaría así

```
<select id="SelectFiltro" name="SelectFiltro" class="form-control form-control-lg select " data-native-menu="false" >
  <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">Ejemplo 1</option>
  <option value="2">Ejemplo 2</option>
  <option value="3">Ejemplo 3</option>
  <option value="4">Ejemplo 4</option>
  <option value="5">Ejemplo 5</option>
  <option value="6" selected="selected">Ejemplo 6</option>
</select>
```

Aclaro que esto hará que "siempre" quede seleccionado por default la opción 6.
Si lo que buscas es que eso sea variable, podrás utilizar alguna variable en la url del tag  que redirecciones con parámetros. Y en el formulario (dentro de un php) interpretar el parámetro para encender la opción deseada. En tal caso, lo mejor es tener en una base de datos o un array las diversas opciones y luego de interpretar el parámetro que llega desde la url, agregarle selected="selected" a la elegida.

Ojala esta info te ayude.

> EDITO POR DETALLES RECIBIDOS ##############

En el caso que la opción 6 solo se active cuando el redireccionamiento provenga desde el tag A, debes pasar una variable por la url del tag, de manera que al recibirlo en el formulario, lo interprete y así podría activar el select 6.

Para ello puedes utilizar una de las siguientes dos maneras:

1. Agregar una variable a la url del href. Quedaría así

   href="https://localhost:44329/contacto/redir.php?redir=ok"

Esto requiere que la url incluya el archivo php donde tengas el tag A. En el ejemplo puse redir.php, pero podría ser index.php o route.php o lo que fuera. El inconveniente que esta opción no soporta la sección dentro de esta url, ya que la opción redir=ok#contacto no funciona. Así que si puedes convivir sin la sección, esto funcionará bien. Sino probá la siguiente.

2. la otra opción es hacerlo solo con un .htaccess, interpretando la url. Podes agregar opcionalmente algo así

   https://localhost:44329/contacto/redir#contacto

y luego interpretarlo con el .htaccess, agregando la siguiente línea de código en el mismo:

```
# pe: contacto/redir#contacto -> index.php?redir=ok#contacto
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^contacto/redir#contacto$ index.php?redir=ok#contacto [L]
```

Esto lo que hace es capturar cuando llegue algo del tipo contacto/redir#contacto y lanzar un comando a un archivo interno llamado index.php con el parametro redir=ok.
Lo bueno en esta opción es que no perdes la sección.

Al final debes interpretar la variable.
En el formulario agrega una línea de código php para recibir e interpretar la variable. Y dependiendo de como salga, activas o no el select. Esto quedaría así

```
<?php $sel = (isset($_GET['redir']) && $_GET['redir']!='ok') ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ; ?>
<select id="SelectFiltro" name="SelectFiltro" class="form-control form-control-lg select " data-native-menu="false" >
  <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">Ejemplo 1</option>
  <option value="2">Ejemplo 2</option>
  <option value="3">Ejemplo 3</option>
  <option value="4">Ejemplo 4</option>
  <option value="5">Ejemplo 5</option>
  <option value="6" <?php echo $sel;?> >Ejemplo 6</option>
</select>
```

Ojala esta info sea de tu utilidad.

Comment: Esta opción es valida solo cuando en el formulario quieras que ese valor 6 este siempre seleccionado, lo que busco es que este seleccionado al momento de redireccionar desde la pagina anterior, cuando no sea así o se ingrese al formulario normal pues va a cargar la opción 0 por defecto.

Comment: ok. En tal caso debes hacer dos cosas:
- en el tag A, agregar un parámetro GET para identificar una variable con algún dato que puedas validar previo al select.
- previo al select incorporar un interprete de dicho parámetro que active la opción 6 si es correcta. Edito el código mas arriba

Comment: Editaste el código, aun no veo una actualización en tu respuesta

Comment: ahi lo sumé. llevo un rato porque no es facil lo que buscas :)